# FileSystemWatcher not detecting mp4 files

Tags: video, powershell-3.0, filesystemwatcher

The script below should watch for ".mp4" files in the specified folder and log an event when a file is created and stop running. But on running the script, it doesn't detect the mp4 files when created but only displays the job as not started (even when a pre-existing .mp4 file is present in the folder, it still displays the job as not started). For filters, I tried using "*.mp4*", "input.mp4", and "*input.mp4*", but no luck with file detection.

What additional edits would be required to get the script to detect these mp4 files?

[image: Created input.mp4 file getting detected by Get-ChildItem]
[image: Job status after input.mp4 file creation]

```bsh
### SET FOLDER TO WATCH + FILES TO WATCH + SUBFOLDERS YES/NO
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "D:\Script\Powershell"
$watcher.Filter = "*input.mp4*"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  
$loop = $true

### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER AN EVENT IS DETECTED
$action = {
    #LOG EVENT
    $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
    $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
    $logline = "$(Get-Date), $changeType, $path"
    Add-Content "D:\log.txt" -Value $logline

    ###Stop whileloop  after filedetection
    $script:loop = $false
}   

### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED
while ($loop) {
    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $watcher "Created" -Action $action
    #Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action $action
    #Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Deleted" -Action $action
    #Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Renamed" -Action $action
    (Start-Sleep -s 1)
}

#UNREGISTER EVENT
Unregister-Event -SubscriptionId 1 -Verbose
```

**EDIT 1**
The above script never entered the "action block" and  hence there was no files detected , so I added a **New-event Script** (line 15) in the action block.But still it  does not enter it and execute the action {of 'write-output "Action Started"' in this case}.Please let me know ,what additional edits are required to execute the action block.

[Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rH8cm.jpg)

```
### SET FOLDER TO WATCH 
  $watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
  $watcher.Path = "D:\Script\Powershell"
  $watcher.Filter = "*input.mp4*"
  $watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
  $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  
  $loop = $true


### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER AN EVENT IS DETECTED

  $action = {New-Event  -SourceID "Ps1.FileCreated"  #<--New-event Added

    Write-output "Action Start" #<--OutputAction started to Console  

    #LOG EVENT
    $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
    $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
    $logline = "$(Get-Date), $changeType, $path"
    Add-content "D:\log.txt" -value $logline



    ###Change $loop value after compression

    $Script:loop  = $false
    Write-Output "Action Stopped" #<--OutputAction stopped to Console  


} 


### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED 

  while ($loop) {

    Write-Output "Loop Entered "

    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $watcher "Created"  -Action $action 

    <#
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action $action
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Deleted" -Action $action
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Renamed" -Action $action
    #>
    Write-Output "Loop Exit "
    (Start-Sleep -s 1);
  }


#UNREGISTER EVENT
    Unregister-Event -SubscriptionId 1 -Verbose
```

Comment: Did you get this solved? If so, could you post the details?

Answer (score 0):

No loop is required.

```
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "D:\Temp"
$watcher.Filter = "*.mp4*"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  
$action = {
    Write-Host $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
}
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $watcher -EventName "Created" -Action $action
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but if I am not mistaken your script is going to exit on the very first attempt as soon as it does not find an mp4 file in the folder.I am trying to render a ,mp4 video file with a videoeditor and once the render finishes it is detected and picked up by handbrake for further processing(handbrake code not provided).For that the powershell script has to loop to check if the .mp4 file has finished rendering ,